# How to prove this series converges by the comparison test?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1+n^{5/2}}$

I'm having trouble coming up with a related fraction that I know is convergent or divergent to find the solution to this

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{1+n^{5/2}}
\lt \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{n^{5/2}}
=\dfrac1{n^2}
$.

If you don't want to compare,
note that
$\dfrac1{n^2}
\lt \dfrac1{n(n-1)}
= \dfrac1{n-1}-\dfrac1{n}
$
which telescopes
(although you have to start at
$n=2$, not $n=1$).

Answer (score 1):

You have $$ {\sqrt{n}\over 1 + n^{5/2} } \sim {1\over n^2}.$$
The limit comparison test makes this very easy.  A small tweak will give you the regular comparison test.